# How to move to another jquery ui tab on button click event in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Could any one help me on how to navigate from one jquery ui tab to another on the click event of a button in asp.net?  In my project i have two jquery ui tabs in one i need to perform some database search based on the ex: empName, DoB etc and when the user clicks on the search button the result of search should be shown in a gridview which is placed on second tab but it is not working
i know how to navigate between jquery ui tabs using  and html button but when i am using **asp button** it is not working i think it is because it has runat="server"..... i am totally confused and stack any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you add a little code so that others can help you easily?

Comment: @mohayemin i am just asking how to navigate between jquery ui tabs on the click event of a button in asp.net not in any html button or href (a) tag, it is just a simple question doesn't require any code in above i gave elaboration inorder to show my requirement more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is that:

Suppose you have a this code in javascript to open the second tab:

```
 $('div').tab2();   // dummy javascript code
```

Then in the button click event you can do this:

```
 protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

   // Code

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "$('div').tab2();", true);

 }
```

Comment: @Hardworker I hope this will solve your problem and thats what i conclude from the question you wrote

Comment: thanks for the reply, exactly my question is in this regard and i did what you told but still after clicking the button it is just postbacking on the same tab:
protected void btnSubmitSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "$('#btnSubmitSearch').click(function () {$('#tab').tabs('select', 1);return false;});", true);}

Comment: YOu need to use this only:  $('#tab').tabs('select', 1); only and not this $('#btnSubmitSearch').click(function () {$('#tab').tabs('select', 1);return false;});

Answer (score 0):

An <asp:Button ...> attaches javascript code to the click event automatically to cause a [postback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback) which is overriding the change tabs behavior you have specified in your code.  (Depending on how you attach your handler, you may actually notice the tabs flicker momentarily before the age reloads).

## If you need the postback

For example, you have process the DB search on the server and set the DataSource of the gridview.  You can use a hidden field on the page to store which tab should be visible at startup, then set that in your click event.  This example assumes you have two tabs named tab1 and tab2.

```
<!-- In your .aspx file -->
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="tabToShowOnLoad" Value="tab1" />
```

```
//In the js function which creates your tabs
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourTabContainer").tabs();
    $("#yourTabContainer").tabs("select", $("#tabToShowOnLoad").val());
});
```

```vb
'In your code behind
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Code you use to run the db search

    tabToShowOnLoad.Value = "tab2"
End Sub
```

## If you don't need the postback

For example you run the search and databind using ajax (with an UpdatePanel or similar).  There's no reason to use an <asp:Button ...>.  Just switch to a classic <input type="button"> and avoid the headache.